# How can I query Row number in this way

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling to get query and set `row_number` in this way. Could anyone give me a way to set row number like this?

```
ProjectID|RevisionYear|Row_Number|
1        |2016        |1         |
1        |2017        |2         |
1        |2017        |2         |
2        |2019        |1         |
2        |2019        |1         |
2        |2020        |2         |
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`. As is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), this function *returns the rank of each row within a result set partition, with no gaps in the ranking values* and the *rank of a specific row is one plus the number of distinct rank values that come before that specific row*:

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   ProjectID, 
   StartYear, 
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY StartYear) AS Row_Number
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 2016),
   (1, 2017),
   (1, 2017),
   (2, 2019),
   (2, 2019),
   (2, 2020)
) v (ProjectID, StartYear)
```

Result:

```
ProjectID   StartYear   Row_Number
1           2016        1
1           2017        2
1           2017        2
2           2019        1
2           2019        1
2           2020        2
```